# Using std::function for member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, std, std-function, member-functions

My question is about using std::function to class methods. Suppose I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "In Foo::print()" << endl;
    }

    virtual void print(int) {
        cout << "In Foo::print(int)" << endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    virtual void print() override {
        cout << "In Bar::print()" << endl;
    }

    virtual void print(int) override {
        cout << "In Bar::print(int)" << endl;
    }
}
```

Now there is another function which is supposed to dynamically call one of the two class methods depends on its input:

```
void call(Foo* foo, void (Foo::*func)(void)) {
    (foo->*func)();
}

Foo* foo = new Foo();
Bar* bar = new Bar();
call(foo, &Foo::print);
call(bar, &Foo::print);
```

When I compile the above code snippet using g++/clang++, it works as expected, where the output is:

```
In Foo::print()
In Bar::print()
```

My questions are then:

1. since there are two functions (overloaded) with the same name: print, when I pass the address of class function: `&Foo::print`, how did the compiler know that I am actually calling `Foo::print(void)` but not `Foo::print(int)`?
2. is there another way that I can generalize the code above such that the second parameter of `void call(Foo*, xxx)` can be passed using both `Foo::print(void)` and `Foo::print(int)`
3. is there anyway to achieve this feature using new feature in C++11 `std::function` ? I understand that in order to use `std::function` with a non-static class method, I have to use `std::bind` to bind each class method with a specific class object, but that would be too inefficient for me because I have many class objects to be bound.

Comment: You said in prototype `call(Foo* foo, void (Foo::*func)(void))`, thus you'll get `(void)` overload

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux that's right. But when I give `&Foo::print` when passing the argument, how did the compiler decide which to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there are two functions (overloaded) with the same name: `print`, when I pass the address of class function: `&Foo::print`, how did the compiler knows that I am actually calling `Foo::print(void)` but not `Foo::print(int)`?

This is allowed because of   [over.over]/p1:

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a
>   pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set.

The compiler can use the target type of the parameter-type-list to determine which function from the overload set the pointer-to-member refers:

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a
>   pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function
>   template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. The function selected
>   is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context. [ Note: .. ] The target can be
>
> — an object or reference being initialized (8.5, 8.5.3, 8.5.4),
>        — the left side of an assignment (5.18),
>        **— a parameter of a function (5.2.2),**
>         — [..]

The name `Foo:print` represents an overload set which the compiler looks through to find a match. The target type `Foo::print(void)` is present in the overload set, so the compiler resolves the name to that overload.

> Is there another way that I can generalize the code above such that the second parameter of `void call(Foo*, xxx)` can be passed using both `Foo::print(void)` and `Foo::print(int)`

There isn't a general way to do it with the name itself. The name has to be resolved to an overload. Instead, try changing the code to accept a function object like a lambda:

```
template<class Callable>
void call(Foo* foo, Callable&& callback) {
    callback(foo);
}

int main()
{
    call(foo, [] (Foo* f) { f->print(); f->print(1); });
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! The explanation of overloaded set rather than a single name makes perfect sense to me and the last lambda trick with move semantics is both elegant and efficient. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, `std::bind` is (almost) entirely outmoded by C++11 lambdas. Don't use std::bind if you can help it. One of these is much clearer than the others, using your example code:

```
const auto lambda  = [=] { foo->print(); }; // Clear!
const auto binderv = std::bind( static_cast<void(Foo::*)()>( &Foo::print ), foo ); // Gets the void version
const auto binderi = std::bind( static_cast<void(Foo::*)(int)>( &Foo::print ), foo, std::placeholders::_1 ); // Gets the int version

//const auto binderv2 = std::bind( &Foo::print, foo ); // Error! Can't tell which Foo::print()
//const auto binderi2 = std::bind( &Foo::print, foo, std::placeholders::_1 ); // Error! Can't tell which Foo::print()

lambda();   // prints "void"
binderv();  // prints "void"
binderi(1); // prints "int"
```

Second, how does the compiler know which overloaded function to call? The same way it would if you were using non-member functions:

```
#include <iostream>

void call( void (*fn)() )
{
    fn();
}

void print()    { std::cout << "void\n"; }
void print(int) { std::cout << "int\n";  }

int main()
{
    call( &print ); // prints "void"
}
```

Only one of those overloaded functions fits the called function's prototype, so the compiler knows. In the case of `std::bind` above, it can't quite tell, but you can force it with a cast, as I did.

Lambdas or `std::function` can wrap either of the member functions, but note that you can't overload a function on different `std::function` signatures. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732106/201787).

---

*Update*:

The right way to handle your question #3 -- to have one function call functions with drastically different signatures like yours -- is to use some intermediary like a functor (lambda, `std::function`, `std::bind`, hand-rolled functor) to erase the differences.

`std::function<void()>` objects that have the same signature, regardless of what the real functions you're calling have as their signature. `std::function` is more expensive (in terms of storing and calling) than a lambda but it has the advantage of having a typename that you can use if you need to store it in a container or something. Lambdas can sometimes be inlined away by the compiler if you play your cards right, so efficiency may still favor lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! `const auto lambda` is good but it won't work for me because I have a lot of such objects like foo, say, > 1000. I am assuming using such techniques I have to create a separate lambda for each such object, which would be very inefficient. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah right, I agree. Anyway, thanks for the solution!